# Selecting row does not show correct amount of selected rows in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Goal:
If I select the main checkbox (id="bbbbbb") whether I have selected one or many row, the `<div id="selectionRows"></div>` should show all the selected row.

Problem:
THe function doesn't work in IE and I have tried thinking about how to solve it but I failed.

[image]

Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#candy input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
      $('#dd').removeClass('selected');

      updateSelectionCounter();
    } else {
      $('#bbbbbb').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
      $('#dd').removeClass('selected');

      updateSelectionCounter();
    }
  });

  $('#bbbbbb').click(function() {
    var checked = $("#bbbbbb").is(':checked');
    $(".asdf").each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', checked);
      if (checked) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
      }
    });
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});


$("#bbbbbb input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});

$(".item input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});

function updateSelectionCounter() {
  var selectedRows = $(".item input[name='nameselected']:checked").length;
  var totalRows = $(".item").length;
  $("#selectionRows").text(selectedRows + ' of ' + totalRows + ' selected rows');
}
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background-color: #FEF0BF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="candy" >
  <tr id="dd">
    <th id="rowLength"><input type="checkbox" id="bbbbbb" /></th>
    <th width="20">a</th>
    <th width="20">b</th>
    <th width="20">c</th>
    <th width="20"">d</th>
    <th width="20">e</th>
    <th width="20">f</th>
    <th width="20">g</th>
    <th width="20">h</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected"  /></td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>                                 
  </tr>
  <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected" /></td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>                                  
  </tr>
    <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected" /></td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>                                  
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div id="selectionRows"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know If i've understood your problem but it's working. What's wrong with your function ?

Comment: If I have selected one row only and then I press the main checkbox(id="bbbbbb")  that is  it is supposed to show all selected number in the id="selectionRows"></div> . THe result is supposed to be three and not one.

Comment: It's working great for me, if I select the row "vvvvvvv" and then the first one I get "3 of 3 selected rows"

Comment: The code works just fine when you run it in this snippet.

Comment: Please take a look at the uploaded picture.

Comment: What browser? Following the  steps shown in images I see correct values in Firefox and in Chrome

Comment: Bug happens in IE, the count was delayed, when you mark all nothing changes, when you deselect all, the script says 3 of 3

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in IE updateSelectionCounter() is executed before the checkboxes are checked, so the function only see all the 3 checkeds when you call the function again.

I "solve" this in snippet adding a timeout in the function, to show you the problem, i'm looking for the reason why IE do this different from chrome and firefox, if i found a good solution i will upload this answer, but with this i believe that at least the problem is exposed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#candy input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
      $('#dd').removeClass('selected');

      updateSelectionCounter();
    } else {
      $('#bbbbbb').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
      $('#dd').removeClass('selected');

      updateSelectionCounter();
    }
  });

  $('#bbbbbb').click(function() {
    var checked = $("#bbbbbb").is(':checked');
    $(".asdf").each(function() {
      $(this).prop('checked', checked);
      if (checked) {
        $(this).parents('tr').addClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(this).parents('tr').removeClass('selected');
        $('#dd').removeClass('selected');
      }
    });
  });

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});


$("#bbbbbb input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});

$(".item input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
  updateSelectionCounter();
});

function updateSelectionCounter() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var selectedRows = $(".item input[name='nameselected']:checked").length;
    var totalRows = $(".item").length;
    $("#selectionRows").text(selectedRows + ' of ' + totalRows + ' selected rows');
  }, 350);
}
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background-color: #FEF0BF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="candy" >
  <tr id="dd">
    <th id="rowLength"><input type="checkbox" id="bbbbbb" /></th>
    <th width="20">a</th>
    <th width="20">b</th>
    <th width="20">c</th>
    <th width="20"">d</th>
    <th width="20">e</th>
    <th width="20">f</th>
    <th width="20">g</th>
    <th width="20">h</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected"  /></td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>
    <td>v</td>                                 
  </tr>
  <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected" /></td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>e</td>                                  
  </tr>
    <tr class = "item">
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="asdf" name="nameselected" /></td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>q</td>                                  
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<div id="selectionRows"></div>
```